# Can I treat all what I typed after a command as raw string?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, quoting

I made a bash func for myself so I can through some words into a tree_hole file, it looks like this in bashrc:

```
function th { echo -e "\n$@" >> /Users/zen1/zen/pythonstudy/tree_hole; }
export -f th
```

Thus I can do `th Tom, I like your new laptop` to cat the whole "Tom ..." sentence to the end of tree_hole file.

But there is a problem. This function seems didn't convert all the part of variables into raw string. So `th "hi, Tom"` will got `hi Tom` instead of the intended `"hi, Tom"`, the `"` is missing. Besides, I can not type a single `'` or `"` or `, which will be misinterpreted by bash and requires more input.

So, is there a way that I can type anything followed a command as raw string? Or how should I improve my function so the special `"`, `'`, ` issue could be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want isn't possible. You don't like the shell behaviour but this part of the shell behaviour cannot be changed.

I guess this would work better for you:

```
function th { { echo; cat; } >> /Users/zen1/zen/pythonstudy/tree_hole; }
```

Your function would be called without parameters. `cat` would read from standard input and append to the file. You could type everything the terminal allows you (i.e. no problems with `"`, `'`, newline and so on). You would end the input with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: Sounds wonderful!